# Python pass while value to function using lambda

Tags: function, lambda, parameter-passing

I am trying to pass a while value to a function so that I don't have to write lots of code.

IamInfo is an array of information
example:
0:  JobNo : JobCode : List of items (again variable length)

My code:

```
q=0
while q < len(IamInfo):
  Left.insert(INSERT,IamInfo[q][2]+"\n")
  Left.bind("<Button-1>", lambda event, arg=q: displayMore(arg))
  q += 1
```

Ineed to pass the q value as I use it as a key to display the last column of information in another tkinter frame.
the length of IamInfo can change from 2 items to 20 so I need to be able to use this for many different number of items.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H0UYI.png)

called function

```
def displayMore(key):
  print (key)                  <--- so I can see what is passed only
  DisLoop = len(IamInfo[key])
  disx = 4                     <--- defines array element to display
  while disx < DisLoop:
    disText = str(IamInfo[key][disx])+"\n"
    Right.insert(INSERT, disText)
    disx += 1
```

With the above code it only passes the last q value for all links.
I have tried several different ways, but either fails or just passes last q value.

Any help would be great.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I resolved this by changing how I called the function.

Instead of:

```
Left.insert(INSERT,IamInfo[q][2]+"\n")
  Left.bind("<Button-1>", lambda event, arg=q: displayMore(arg))
```

I used:

```
but=Button(Left,width=25,text=IamInfo[q][1],command= partial(displayMore,key=q)).pack()
```

This called the function with while passing the loop value at the time of creation.